# Interstellar communcation with FTL

Tags: science-based, technology, communication, faster-than-light

I am designing a world where humans have achieved FTL by means of the Alcubierre warp drive and are colonizing the stars. 
Originally I had communication pegged as being done with quantum entanglement and the like, but I recently heard of the no-communication theorem that, seemingly, prevents this from coming to fruition. Now, from a narrative perspective it is not strictly speaking necessary that communication is fairly instant, but it's a ton more convenient. Therefore I'd to find a way for it to be so using existing theories or reasonable speculation.

- Is there a hole in the no-communication theorem that can be exploited to permit it anyway?
- Is there other, speculated methods of instantaneous communication?

Otherwise I am relying on communication being done with warp drives, that is, every settled planet will have a comm station in orbit that every day/hour/minute sends out a comm drone through warp space with the most recent and updated info to other settled planets, likely in a branching fashion so that A sends to B and then B sends to B1-B9 and B1 sends to B1,1-B1,9 and so on. Now, warp isn't instant, it takes about a week or two to travel across inhabited space (approximately 400 ly in radius), so that creates a lot of delay

- Is there a more efficient solution when you use warp as a basis for interstellar communication?

I don't want to have to rely on a lot of "magic" technology, but if something is reasonable speculated/theorized to be possible within the realm of physics (albeit past the capabilities of humans to reproduce at all anno 2015), I'm interested.

Comment: This one is your solution. The particle is hypotetical, but that should be fine for fiction. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon

Comment: There's a massive problem with using tachyons, they travel into the past which would make it a pretty major thing in the setting.

Comment: As well as there are massive problems in using warp-drones. There are always problems in causality when scifi bends the laws of physic. For example, how would you practically produce a warp field?

Comment: I'm reading on quantum teleportation hoping to send information via entanglement through a tiny boom tube.

Comment: The real limit on FTL communication is Special Relativity... forces always propagate at c within an inertial frame, FTL comms would allow information about an object outrun it's gravitational and electromagnetic force upon you.  You're probably best off either using tachyons as mentioned below or else adopting ultrawave.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyonic_antitelephone

Comment: Since we have the FTL drive as a given (and I suppose causalty and time travel are hand waved), then there is no reason that messages would  not be sent via "Pony Express". A ship full of flash drives would essentially be a "sneaker net" with more bandwidth than most other proposed ideas, and so long as security is taken into account, quite safe as well.

Comment: I don't understand how this question is meaningful... you've got FTL travel, but not communication? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: The Alcubierre warp drive still violates causality and requires magic matter, so be ready to deal with that.

Comment: how about telepathy? Using telepaths as comms officers. Or does that not exist in your virtual universe?

Comment: Welcome to the site, fred. We encourage answers to be full length, as opposed to a few snippets of suggestion. If you could expand this answer to how telepathy might allow for interstellar communication, it would be appreciated. Otherwise, this should really have been a comment.

Comment: Humans had globe-spanning empires before electronic forms of communication, where the delay between the most distant parts of the empire was measured in months, and they still managed to keep everything running. So a week of delay shouldn't be such a great problem.

Comment: @vsz To be fair, it was only months for low priority communication. Most empires had the means to send messages much faster when needed - but that still works for Llama's setting; low priority communication would be   handled by normal freighters, while high priority would be handled by fast blockade runners, for example.

Comment: FWIW, this approach is used in Variable Star by Robinson and Heinlein.

Answer (score 5):

Just reading up on what an Alcubierre drive is, and it seems to work by shrinking space in front of an object to allow the object to travel through the space faster than light.

Could you use the same principle for sending data? i.e. instead of a "warp bubble", have a warp tunnel? An almost infinitely thin (to minimise the size of it and therefore the energy required) line of shrunken space between the transmitter and the receiver through which data can be sent.

Comment: Cannot imagine how you want to shrink space per "remote", thus you need a moving device. This would basicly be a warp-drone which has disadvantages due many limitations.

Comment: @Sempie: As fur as I understand, it is one of the problems of the Alcubierre drive, that the bubble must be controlled from outside. So maybe it is not a big difference, whether there is a ship or e.g. radio waves inside.

Comment: @Sempie the transmitter would be similar to the device on the spaceship, except that the "bubble" would be very long, but very thin and reach all the way to the receiver (or a relay station)

Comment: If you could produce a warped bit of space that would stable, like a soliton, then you shoot the warped solitons themselves as messages, some kind of dot-dash system. Might make an interesting weapon as well.

Comment: @BartekChom the problem with "putting radio waves" in a Alcubierre drive is that when that reigon of space is returned to normal, [all the energy / particles / light that is swept up in the transit is released](http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/140635-the-downside-of-warp-drives-annihilating-whole-star-systems-when-you-arrive). Assuming that this isn't pointed at the destination (and wiping it out), the issue is one of trying to get the actual signal out of the noise of the 'stop'.

Comment: @MichaelT Thank you. It is worth taking into account. We could try to work this around assuming that signal radio waves are stronger than the noise sent in the same direction as theirs.

Answer (score 4):

It's simple, just invent a widgit that corrects for the quantum issues and use quantum entanglement for communication. Keep in mind that the Alcubierre drive itself has all sorts of issues within physics. As a nod to Star Trek you could even call them Heisenberg Compensators, since they did exactly that to explain how their teleporters work with the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle.

Another option would be to say that the unmanned drones can travel much faster than crewed ships (maybe due to small size, lack of need to keep squishy organics alive, etc) so you could use drones and adjust the time delay to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

**As mentioned in your question**, quantum entanglement can't actually be used to send non-random information, as a result the only way to send things or information FTL is by using a warp drive (which still relies on theoretical negative energy that may not even exist).

**The warp drive is what you need to get FTL travel**, but it is also the only way to do FTL communication, if you had another way you could probably use it for travel as well.

**It seems the only way to do communications FTL** is going to be communication drones, but the drones would probably send their information in radio waves once they dropped out of FTL near their target.

**Intercepting communications** or stopping them would be tricky, at FTL speeds intercepting anything would be nearly impossible, but once they have dropped out of FTL messages would probably be sent with radio waves, which would entail using the same methods we use today.

**In addition** we *know* that the basic idea behind a warp drive doesn't break any laws like many other proposed FTL. We already know that space itself isn't limited to the speed of light, only matter and energy is. Galaxies sufficiently far away will never have their light reach us due to the expansion of space due to *dark energy*, to us they are effectively using a warp drive go FTL. 
Warp drives are dependent on whether we can harness negative energy, but we already suspect that the fabric of space has negative energy as dark energy, but that would probably be impossible to harness since it's evenly distributed.

Comment: "to us they are effectively using a warp drive go FTL" <-- I've never heard it phrased that way, but I like it.  I'm pretty sure it's wrong but I still like it.  Those galaxies aren't *moving* FTL, it's that space is *expanding* FTL.  It's a subtle difference but the equations care about it.

Comment: But the fact the galaxy itself isn't going FTL, doesn't matter, in fact that's the point. The galaxy only seems to be going FTL but actually it's the space not the matter. That's also exactly what a warp drive does, it warps space so that it can go FTL without *technically* going FTL, just like the galaxies. My point is that the process behind a warp drive already naturally exists in the real world.

Comment: It's not really the same process though... the galaxy isn't moving towards anything, it isn't really moving at all.  The apparent motion is from the light stretching.  One of the consequences of this is that an observer capable of moving FTL would see the *apparent* absolute speed decrease as they approached the galaxy they were measuring.

Comment: The galaxy isn't *"really"* moving, but neither is the Alcubierre drive, the drive merely expands and warps space, the ship could be totally stationary, it moves the space around the ship, instead of moving the ship through space. Also the galaxies inability to ever have their information reach us isn't due to stretching their light (that wouldn't slow it down just lengthen the wavelength) but due to the expansion of space itself which exceeds the speed of light.

Comment: Strictly, the ship is moving in terms of position relative to fixed locations within it's frame of reference even if it isn't moving within the bubble.  I didn't say anything about the ship though.  I said the galaxy wasn't actually moving.  The universe is scaling thus everything remains proportionally distant from everything else.

Comment: Also, I clearly said the apparent motion was due to space expanding faster than light, I didn't say anything about that slowing down light.  What I did say is that if you could travel fast enough for it to be meaningful, as you approach a galaxy the redshift will decrease (due to decreasing time to be stretched) and thus the galaxy will appear to be decelerating even though both you and the galaxy maintain a constant velocity.

Comment: You said the apparent motion is from the light stretching which seemed to imply you were somehow not acknowledging that they were moving but my bad. For the galaxies sufficiently far away of course red-shifting is irrelevant since the light could never reach us. I'm not sure how the fact everything (except things in the same galactic clusters and whatnot) is scaling apart together is important. I'm really not sure what you mean by fixed points of reference for the spaceship it seems that the mechanism behind FTL for warp drives is somewhat analogous to the expansion of space.

Comment: @VakusDrake That's the usual interpretation of how warping space allows FTL travel, but it doesn't actually work. The key point is the roundtrip - as long as you only care about one-way trip, it can *appear* to be FTL (e.g. as far as your onboard clock is concerned, you just travelled a light year in an hour), but when you add the trip back, you'll see it took two years anyway. The same applies to those distant galaxies - there's no roundtrip FTL. Whether you use warp or wormholes, you still have to deal with the time dilation; anything else would blow causality out of the window.

Comment: @Luaan There's no round-trip FTL for the galaxies because the warp effect is evenly distributed, but if we know this kind of spacial warping exists then it should be possible in theory even if other issues make it impossible. Anyway I still don't see how this is supposed to violate causality, wormholes potentially could because they could connect into the past but a warp drive just shortens the distance needed to travel.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the expansion of the universe is happening at every level, the same thing that makes galaxies appear to be moving also applies all the way down to atomic scales, it's just impossible to measure at anything less than stellar scales.  An important bit about relative motion is that galaxies aren't moving *towards* anything, thus don't violate relativity.  Think about the expansion this way: if you draw two dots on a balloon and then inflate it, the dots don't move but have apparent motion relative to each other.  Replace dots with galaxies, etc.

Comment: @Luaan Right but warp drives don't actually move a spaceship either they move the space around it. Of course the warping of space due to expansion isn't going to be visible in galaxy clusters, since it is overcome by gravity, but the important point is that in neither case is any actual motion taking place it merely acts like motion but since it's the space that's being affected it doesn't qualify.

Comment: @VakusDrake Yes, that's the standard sci-fi handwaving - just like the standard handwave for wormholes is that they either drill their way "through the paper", or that space is *shorter* inside the wormhole. The thing is, we know what it looks like when spacetime is distorted - it manifests as gravity. But gravity doesn't violate the speed of light either, and neither would the hypothetical "anti"-gravity needed for warp. There is a symmetry to space-time - if you "stretch it out" (e.g. shorten the distance), you must also slow down time.

Comment: @Luaan I'm not sure gravity bends space the same way exactly that i'm describing. Gravity affects time and high speeds may affect distance, but i'm not sure gravity by itself is enough to warp distances, though relativistic speeds can do that.

Comment: @VakusDrake Well, to be more exact, gravity *is* warped space. There's no distinction - the two are the same (although in theory, space could be warped "both ways", while gravity is always attractive - if we ever observe this, we'll probably have to redefine gravity). It's fascinating how brilliantly the whole of relativity fits together - how it manages to build the relativistic universe entirely on local laws, with no absolute frame of reference. It's hard to wrap your head around - try http://tinyurl.com/einrel for a great intro. It will change your look at the universe :)

Comment: @Luaan I'v watched pbs spacetime which has some pretty great videos on relativity :), I get that gravity warps space, but I'm just not sure that it can increase or decrease distances like the way warp drives (or the expansion of space) are supposed to work. Though warp drives do require negative energy. I just don't know of any examples of gravity being able to distort distances, despite it being able to distort time, and the fact that high speed can distort both space and time. It seems like gravity ought to change distances but I'v never heard of it, plus a warp drive would be using mass.

Comment: @VakusDrake That's just the difference between TV relativity and the actual theory, I'm affraid. It *is* considered a difficult topic. It seems like it didn't cover how gravity is not a real force in relativity, just the result of the particular spacetime distortion. High speeds "distortions" are just another special case of the general theory. The problem is, trying to separate the space and time part of spacetime is flawed - it only works for non-relativistic scenarios, otherwise you simply have to consider it as one. Mass/energy distorts space time. This distortion manifests as gravity.

Comment: @Luaan I'm sure pbs spacetime covered it, but alas the host knows what he's talking about, but I didn't quite catch everything, you can  only make things so simple. So... I'm still not sure why exactly sure why gravity doesn't warp distances like speed can, there must be a good answer, after all i'm not confusing the map with the territory.

Comment: @VakusDrake I wouldn't even suggest the host didn't know what he's talking about - he'd still have to do some "dumbing down", though. And that's where you lose a lot of the subtleties, ultimately preventing you from the real "Aha!" moment. It took me years of trying again and again before I finally got it, right to the point where I can write out the equations describing situations like this (though not *solve* them, of course :D). If you're interested, the Physics stack exchange would be a perfect place to ask additional questions :)

Comment: @Luaan Yeah I meant that since he couldn't simplify relativity past a certain point, it is rather hard to grasp, I expect he probably got everything right, but in doing so it makes it hard to get your head around. You seem to have a better background in the subject, so you might be able to actually get most of the videos on the first viewing.

Comment: @VakusDrake Hmm, I checked it out, and I was pleasantly surprised - I didn't check all of the videos, but with some watching and skipping, I didn't catch anything that would be outright misleading. Although I *hate* this video format, it's very distracting :P Try watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AwhKZ3fd9JA and all the prerequisites and pausing once in a while, even watching it a few times.  And really *think* about the implications - it seems like you already have lots of the knowledge, but you didn't use it to invalidate your prior understanding yet - just take the next step.

Comment: @Luaan I don't know that i'm really very close to getting relativity, I don't even get how a absolute speed limit could be possible without a absolute frame of reference, but that *is* clearly how the universe works.

Comment: @VakusDrake Yeah, I think you still don't quite grok that space and time just aren't separable. There's just one spacetime, and the distinction between time and space is just a thing of our perception, not a fundamental thing about the universe. That doesn't mean that `v = at^2` no longer holds of course, it does; it's just that it only really applies when you're limiting your view to discount relativity - we perceive ourselves moving through time at some fixed pace, so we perceive other things doing the same, even though there isn't any such thing (... this is hard to explain in words :D).

Comment: @Luaan Yeah I mean anyone can understand that time and space are interconnected and such, but just knowing that, you just know a phrase you don't actually understand anything. I can hardly say I could extrapolate circumstances in relativity, where I didn't already know the answers, which would be the truest test of comprehension.

Comment: @VakusDrake Try rewatching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P4rW_pPbD-U a few times - it addresses the issue specifically. After a few times (and really, do keep pausing and repeating parts of the video - it's very hard to think straight in this format), you should be able to understand the "priviledged position" of light (and other massless particles). It should also show how absurd the notion of any travel that would appear faster than light is. I think this is one of the big barriers to general relativity - to stop thinking about spacetime as some time variable slapped onto space.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this kind of scifi is bending the laws of physics. Thus, you can fully legit use hypothetical particles which aren't proofed to exist yet.

So your solution is as simple as it can be:

[Tachyon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon)

> A tachyon /ˈtæki.ɒn/ or tachyonic particle is a hypothetical particle that always moves faster than light. [sic]

[...]

> They have been used as a standby mechanism upon which many science fiction authors rely to establish **faster-than-light communication**
>   [sic]

A common mechanic is sending a tachyon beam to the communication target. 
Behaves pretty much like any light beam (Just faster), can be detected or blocked by objects on their way.

**But even Tachyons would have a big problem.**
When the tachyon wants to reach a spacecraft from behind, it has to pass streched space, which will make it relatively slow, maybe so slow, that it needs aeons to reach the spacecraft.

**There are two solutions for this:**
1. Warp-drive is slower than tachyons by the manner that the time a tachyon beam needs to pass the negative warp-space is reasonable.
2. Spacecraft has to stop or throttle warp-drive to get the tachyon-delay reasonable.

First solution has the disadvantage, that the spacecraft has to move slower than it might could.
Second solution has the disadvantage, that you can't tell the crew "hey guys, I wanna talk to you, throttle down please." due you can't communicate currently. Thus, the spacecraft would have to throttle down periodic and the in-warp communication would have a protocoll like:
Once in t(xy) the spacecraft throttles to speed v(tachyon)-xyz), then communication is done, then the spacecraft accelerates again.

Comment: If you allow tachyons, then you also allow communication into the past, so that's a problem. Tachyons don't just travel faster than light, they also travel into the past. Warp drives don't have this problem because they aren't *technically* FTL.

Comment: Well, tachyons are faster than light, while warp is shorter than space. These are two concepts of time-travel. I don't see the problem.

Comment: If the writer allows tachyons they are also allowing communication back in time. I somewhat doubt the writer wants to introduce time travel into the setting.

Comment: Warp drives conversely don't allow time-travel they simply exploit a sort of loophole.

Comment: While you're not wrong, this isn't more than a game with words...

Comment: The reasons you can do FTL with a warp drive is the same reason space can be FTL. Some distant galaxies will never have their light reach us because they are effectively retreating faster than light, due the expansion of the universe, physical mass can't go FTL but the fabric of space itself doesn't have that restriction. That's why if negative energy exists it should allow FTL, because we already know that variety of FTL exists.

Comment: Personally I like the idea that ships have to drop out of FTL to communicate outside the bubble, gives you a good plot limitation to play with.

Comment: @VakusDrake - having Tachyons go backward in time doesn't seem like a problem. You just capture the signal before you need it at some receiving station... to avoid time paradoxes, have the receiver encrypt the messages with the decryption key tied to the current time so the message can't be unlocked early. Then you just load the database of stored messages on the ship before it leaves and they can decrypt the messages meant for them when it's time to receive them.

Comment: @Johnny So essentially your method of preventing paradoxes is the honor system? Really?

Comment: @VakusDrake - no my method of allowing FTL communications requires the honor system to prevent time paradoxes, but if the technology to send messages to the past exists, there will always be people who will abuse it, so there's no harm in having the "good guys" rely on the honor system.

Comment: @Johnny But if anybody ever uses it for time travel (of information) then the  writer will have to resolve time paradoxes and deal with time travel. Plus I really doubt people would even bother trying to institute honor system in the first place, it is near impossible to enforce and there would be massive advantages to time travel.

Comment: @VakusDrake - the same could be said of nuclear weapons, what sane government would actually research and build nuclear weapons knowing the destructive potential they hold, knowing that some countries would see a massive advantage to have them, and realizing that restraint for their use depends only on the honor system. And why would they even try to institute an honor system that's nearly impossible to enforce?

Comment: @Johnny The difference here is that time travel is vastly more useful, and the technology is available to basically everyone .

Comment: @VakusDrake Is it available to basically everyone, or can a tachyon receiver only be built at huge expense by a coalition of governments?

Comment: @Johnny Well rarity depends on the setting, but keeping the designs secret would be massively difficult, plus unlike nuclear weapons there are immediate advantages to gaining the tech even if you keep your time machines secret, so nearly everyone would be incentivized to get them.

Comment: @VakusDrake - there's no immediate advantage to being able to send information to the past - you have to build the receiver and wait until some future you can send back some useful information -- perhaps the receiver has such large energy demands or emits some telltale radiation or requires some Unobtanium that needs a processing plant and equipment on par with Uranium enrichment. So you may be discovered before you receive your first message from the future.

Comment: @Johnny Actually I would contest that there is A LOT of uses for time travel. You wouldn't need to get any special equipment beyond that normally used for tachyon communication. If the receiver put out radiation that radiation would be indistinguishable from that put out by normal use so if they claim to be using it legally they don't know anything, otherwise you could shield the radiation deep underground or by interference or really far from civilization, if you can do it anywhere you can likely use that information anywhere. If you made it super hard to make only governments would have it.

Comment: @Johnny Needless to say if only large governments have it that would be a pretty significant element for the story, and the government would probably use it for time travel. Even if the government followed honor system (which they almost certainly wouldn't), they can't prevent any of the many people with access to it along the line from using it. Plus if you make the technology too restrictive, it can't be used for anything but the most important info, so it's not going to be normally used.

Comment: Could you discuss this in the chat please?

Comment: @Sempie - usually I see the "This is a long discussion, do you want to move it to chat" link, but I don't see that here.

Answer (score 2):

Wormholes. Yea, wormholes.  Some theories have them being created and destroyed at the quantum foam level ([Quantum Dynamics of Lorentzian Spacetime Foam](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9309017)). For most things, this isn't practical. Its too small to even push atoms through - on the order of 1000x smaller than a proton.

However, one might be able to push light through it and allow for communication with the other end of the wormhole.

So, what you would do is grab one of these wormhole pairs that is constantly forming, and prevent it from being pulled back into where it came from.  You put one end in the communication center on one planet, and take the other end to the communication center to the other planet.

There are some odd effects that would happen with wormholes that can cause some causality problems which one should be aware of.  Lets take a wormhole and do a four year relativistic speed loop (that to the passage only takes a year).  Now, the wormhole that traveled is three years younger than the one that stayed home.  If you look through it, you would see three years ago (and on the flip side, if you look through the one that stayed home, you would see three years into the future).  There are suggestions that this would cause it to [blow up before anything could happen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_protection_conjecture).  There are possibilities of chronology violation with [rings of wormholes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_ring) too where each end is not causality violating, but the combination is.

A system that wasn't causality violating would be a communication hub.  Each colony has one, and only one, wormhole link to Earth (the location of the hub). Furthermore, colonies are prohibited to have wormhole links to other colonies (if they did, it would form a loop, and with FTL in there would have some causality violation and the virtual particles would pile up on a closed space time curve and cause an excess of energy density which, well, goes 'boom').  This would allow for some imperial censoring and such.

References of hard science fiction with wormholes:

- [The Light of Other Days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light_of_Other_Days) Stephen Baxter based on a synopsis by Arthur C. Clarke (the wormholes are photon sized)
- [Time Master](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0595197590) by [Robert Forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_L._Forward) - full of temporal paradoxes and larger than photon wormholes but has interesting bits on the wormholes (it starts out with "If I receive a letter from this sort of person complaining about the "impossibility" of the time machines in this novel, I will throw the letter in the nearest wastebasket . . . *unless* the letter is accompanied by a reprint of a scientific paper published in *Physical Review* (or any other reputable, refereed scientific journal), written by the person writing the letter, which *proves* that the paper "[Cauchy Problem in Spacetimes with Closed Timelike Curves](http://authors.library.caltech.edu/3737/)" by Friedman, Morris, Novikov, Echeverria, Klinkhammer, Thorne, and Yurtserver, is erroneous.")

Answer (score 1):

Superstring theory postulates that said "strings" are producing worm holes. While too small and volatile to send humans through, information COULD potentially be transmitted through said strings. This kind of goes along with @colmde in relation to small tubes/tunnels instead of bubbles.

Here is a quoted segment on this topic, but Michio Kaku:

"...as a string moves in time, it warps the fabric of space around it, producing black holes, wormholes, and other exotic solutions of Einstein’s equations."

And a useful page of information with more on the topic where the quote was found:

http://mkaku.org/home/articles/blackholes-wormholes-and-the-tenth-dimension/

Answer (score 0):

The bulk of communication can be carried by untrusted traveler ships at reasonable prices, with drones as an expensive fallback in case no-one is going.

Cryptography (heck, even *today's* cryptography) can guarantee no eavesdropping and no tampering with messages. The worst a malicious ship can do is not deliver, in which case it won't get paid.

Answer (score 0):

This is an idea I was going to use in an erstwhile project. It's softer sci-fi than Alcubierre drives, but it might suit.

A special device opens a tiny wormhole to a microscopic pocket universe. These devices are such that a connection can be opened to the same pocket from anywhere in the universe. EM waves can be sent and received, but nothing larger goes in or out.

Again, I'm not sure if this is too soft for you; wormholes are postulated to be possible, as are subatomic black holes, and white holes. Put them all together and there you are.

It also opens some interesting possibilities from a narrative perspective - can they be hacked, how much energy does it take to open the connection, are there limitations in creating/discovering pockets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's true that quantum entanglement cannot be used to send messages. The problem is well explained elsewhere, so I'm not going to dig too deep into it. However, there is a way around this - all you need is a device that destroys the universe.

Say you want to send a message `110`. You have a particle pair that's entangled, so by reading your particle in the pair, you know what the *other* end will read. You'll need to read the particles at predefined intervals and find a way to prevent the entanglement from propagating (it's not really entangled-not entangled, it's more like entangled with one or two other particles versus entangled with billions) - that's a great place for some handwaving. But let's suppose that's solved - you simply found a way to isolate the partice well enough that you only have the two entanglements - one to your sensor device, and another to the other side of the telegraph.

Now, you only have a reader. How do you use it to send messages? Simple!

Read your particle. Does it show `1`? Awesome, bit of data "sent". Does it show `0`? Destroy the universe. This way, the only universes that survive are the ones where the other side reads exactly the data you wanted to send! It may sound brutal, but don't forget that an infinite number of universes dies every second anyway, so you're just exploiting the natural behaviour for your own purposes ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Well-established sci-fi technology: the ansible.
The technology is based on the idea that dimensionality is fictional under some restricted mathematical topologies, which provides an opportunity for non-transit communication.

Your deliberations are correct. Quantum physics requires that a breakdown of causality causes a singularity, and therefore superluminal communication of any sort is barred.